# DNS resolvation of a URL

Tags: dns, ip, nameserver

Can anyone explain the various steps to resolving a domain name to ip address when we type an url example.com in our browser and how it returns the page example.com to user by traversing the source(user) to destination ?

Comment: This question is way too broad.  To answer what you have asked is multiple chapters of a printed book.

Comment: Google would help you if you chose to use it first. Try Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: Thanks Steve and Tyson, But I don't know what is wrong with my question, putting negatives by some people. Have look at http://igoro.com/archive/what-really-happens-when-you-navigate-to-a-url/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my question, and I would like to briefly explain as follows , if some null experts here are put forward negative towards my question.

What happens when we type a url in browser.

1. First Step is to catch the ip address of requested domain.
2. To get hosted contents in domain name example.com it is to be converted to its corresponding ip address.
3. This corresponding ip address is trace out from the ns record of domain name.
4. To find out all records it makes a lookup in dns table, it first searches browser cache to get the dns information of domain, because browser caches dns information for a little time.
5. If the browser cache does not contain the requested record, the browser makes a system call to check it in os cache.
6. If it is not found in os cache the next it is checked in the DNS server of Internet Service provider.
7. ISPs begin a search for finding the name server of example.com using domain extension .com.
8. ISP look ups the dns table or database of .com registry(Verisign) to find out the name server information of our domain example.com, using various fast algorithm techniques, these dns table of example.com consist of information contain ns records of domain example.com and its corresponding ip.
9. If  primary dns and its corresponding ip address responds for the request, it transfers request to primary dns and its corresponding ip.
10. Otherwise if available ,it transfers the request to ns2(secondary dns) and its corresponding ip.
    11.Next step is to check the domain name in NAMED virtual host in the ip address(ip address which responded towards our request) to find its hosted directory location.
11. This directory location contains the files we hosted , which have any of extensions, .html / .php /.asp etc.